# Can pyhdfs make a 'soft' delete?

Tags: python, hdfs, pyhdfs-client

I am using

```
from pyhdfs import HdfsClient

fs = HdfsClient(hosts=..., user_name='hdfs', ..)
fs.delete(path_table, recursive=True)
```

However, after I deleted the directory, I could not find it in the trash directory located in `/user/hdfs/.Trash/Current/`.

Does it look like the pyhdfs deletes the files with `'-skipTrash'`? How to make it softly delete the target? I could not find method like `'-mv'` to implement this request manually, either.

This is the description from the official document:
[image]

Comment: What is `-skipTrash`? [All pyhdfs seems to do is issue a WebHDFS `DELETE` request against the resource given.](https://github.com/jingw/pyhdfs/blob/master/pyhdfs/__init__.py#L626-L637)

Comment: hi @AKX Thanks for your reply. `-skipTrash` is a HDFS delete command: if you run `hdfs dfs -rm xxx`, the target will be moved to a 'trash' directory then it will be finally cleaned after a set retention time, you can find it back. If you use `hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash xxx`, the target will be immediately destroyed. It's dangerous..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `skipTrash`-esque option (or an alternative to not skip the trash) [is documented](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Delete_a_File.2FDirectory) for the WebHDFS delete command.

The `hdfs dfs rm` command [primarily attempts to use the Trash API (unless told not to)](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/shell/Delete.java#L116-L125), and if trashing fails, it deletes the file using what I'd assume is the same underlying operation the WebHDFS API uses.

Trashing seems to be implemented ([(1)](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/9539ff108aaa420168935a3dbc73c43c1686e252/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Trash.java#L73-L97), [(2)](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/9539ff108aaa420168935a3dbc73c43c1686e252/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/TrashPolicyDefault.java#L185-L188)) as a create-directories-and-rename command.

It's likely you would need to implement that sequence by hand when using WebHDFS (and by extension `pyhdfs`).